# Multiple object in mssql-scripter using batch script

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, mssql-scripter

I'm going to use batch script to do export table for the user.
It is possible to export multiple tables to a `*.sql` file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

But in `mssql-scripter` I can't find solution supporting multiple tables.

I'm using this script.

```
mssql-scripter -S SERVER_NAME -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table1 --script-drop-create > ./output.sql
```

I want table1 & table2.

So I split it up into two batch files:

**make_script.bat**

```
set SERVER_NAME=name
start "table1" script\make_table1.bat %SERVER_NAME%
start "table2" script\make_table2.bat %SERVER_NAME%
```

**make_table1.bat**

```
set SERVER_NAME=%1
mssql-scripter -S %SERVER_NAME% -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table1 --script-drop-create > ./table1.sql
exit
```

**make_table2.bat**

```
set SERVER_NAME=%1
mssql-scripter -S %SERVER_NAME% -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table2 --script-drop-create > ./table2.sql
exit
```

It works. But there is problem: `make_table1.bat` and `make_table2.bat` do not close.

I created the two commands in one batch - however now, the second call to `mssql-scripter` is never started.

**make_script.bat**

```
set SERVER_NAME=name
mssql-scripter -S %SERVER_NAME% -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table1 --script-drop-create > ./table1.sql
mssql-scripter -S %SERVER_NAME% -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table2 --script-drop-create > ./table2.sql
```

How do I export two tables?

Comment: So, the docs [specify the parameter](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter/blob/dev/doc/usage_guide.md#include-database-objects) `--include-objects [[...]]` - have you tried using something like a comma-delimited list `--include-objects dbo.table1,dbo.table2` yet?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about that. Using space is correct. `--include-objects dbo.table1 dbo.table2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using space can export mutiple tables.

```
set SERVER_NAME=%1
mssql-scripter -S %SERVER_NAME% -U user -P password -d DatabaseName --schema-and-data --include-objects dbo.table1 dbo.table2 --script-drop-create > ./tables.sql
exit
```